# Drawing in Flash using PHP

Tags: php, flash, draw

Is it possible to draw shapes in a flash animation at runtime through PHP? If so, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AMFPHP](http://www.amfphp.org/) and pull server generated instructions every second.

Another way to do that would be Flash -> Javascript -> PHP, which will require more data piping than Flash -> AMFPHP.

Otherwise, it's unlikely, as PHP is operating on server-side, while Flash/AS3 are running  on client side.

Comment: I hadn't thought about Flash being client-side. Thanks for the link. I assume that Javascript is used as an intermediary in a similar way to AJAX.

Comment: Yep, Javascript will simply POST/GET every time span and pipe it to Flash using the API.